# Proving convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I am reviewing for a final exam and can't seem to figure out how to do this one. This was a question from an exam this semester.

Suppose that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = 0$.

Prove that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|x_n^2 + x_{n+3}\right| < \frac{1}{5}$ for all $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x_n \to 0$, then **there exists an integer** $N$ such that
$$
|x_n|<\frac1{10}, \quad n\geq N,
$$ and we have
$$
|x_n^2+x_{n+3}|\leq|x_n^2|+|x_{n+3}|<\frac1{10}\times\frac1{10}+\frac1{10}<\frac15, \quad n\geq N.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, $\;\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n^{2}+x_{n+3})=0$,

so there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n^{2}+x_{n+3}|<\frac{1}{5}$ for $n\ge N$.